# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ... in node_modules/express-validator/lib/express_validator.js:75

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I am trying to run my project with node server.js and i am getting following error.

```
/Library/WebServer/Documents/PROJECT/node_modules/express-validator/lib/express_validator.js:75
        chain[name] = (...options) => {
                       ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Library/WebServer/Documents/PROJECT/node_modules/express-validator/index.js:1:80)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

I am using Express.js framework. It was working fine last time when i worked on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a lot i finally found that for one of my project which was build with nodejs older version i was using `node@4.4.7` and after changing node version on my local machine with following:

```
nvm ls   // to check out what versions of Node.js are installed on your machine

->       v4.4.7
         v8.9.1
         system
default -> 4.4.7 (-> v4.4.7)
```

To switch Node.js from `node@4.4.7` to `node@8.9.1` i have used following command:

```
nvm use v8.9.1
```

To verify i check again with `nvm ls` and now it shows.

```
    v4.4.7
->       v8.9.1
         system
default -> 4.4.7 (-> v4.4.7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes the spread operator which is  available in ES6 will be available form   versions 8 and above  for  node 8 .

Comment: Wrong -- [it is available starting with version 5](https://node.green/#ES2015-syntax-spread-------operator).